# powershell select-string not working correctly

Tags: powershell, select-string

I'm a beginner to powershell and having I suspect what will be a simple problem. I'm trying to do the following command, but it returns nothing as a result and I don't understand why.

I'm trying to get the description of the current section of bcdedit. If I do:

```powershell
bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3
```

It returns the following:

```
> identifier {current}  
device partition=C:  
path \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe  
description Windows 8.1
```

So why doesn't the following return `description Windows 8.1`?

```powershell
bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3 | select-string "description"
```

Instead it returns nothing at all.

Any information on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't get the result you expect, because `Select-String` doesn't output strings, but [`MatchInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects. If you pipe the output of your first `Select-String` into the `Get-Member` or `Format-List` cmdlet, you'll get something like this:

```
PS C:\> bcdedit /enum | Select-String "identifier.*current" -Context 0,3 | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}

PS C:\> bcdedit /enum | Select-String "identifier.*current" -Context 0,3 | Format-List *

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 17
Line       : identifier              {current}
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : identifier.*current
Context    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext
Matches    : {identifier              {current}
```

The `Line` property contains the actual matching line, and the `Context` property contains child properties with the pre- and post-context. Since the `description` line you're looking for is in the `PostContext` child property, you need something like this for extracting that line:

```
bcdedit /enum | Select-String "identifier.*current" -Context 0,3 |
  Select-Object -Expand Context |
  Select-Object -Expand PostContext |
  Select-String 'description'
```

Bottom line: `Select-String` does work correctly. It just doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Or, slightly simpler, you could use `out-string -stream` to give select-string some strings to search again:  `bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -Context 0,3 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "description"`

Answer (score 5):

`Select-String` returns `MatchInfo` objects, not just the string data displayed.  That data is taken from the `Line` and `Context` properties of the `MatchInfo` object.

Try this:

```
 bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3 | format-list
```

And you'll see the various properties of the `MatchInfo` object.

Note that the `Context` property is displayed as  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext
You'll need to drill down into this object further to get more information:

```
(bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3).context | format-list
```

There you'll see that the `context` property is another object with `PreContext` and `PostContext` properties, where the actual Pre and PostContext lines are.

So:

```
(bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3).Context.PostContext | Select-String 'description'
```

Will get the description line from the postcontext matches.

Or you can do this:

```
[string](bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" -context 0,3) -split "`n" -match 'description'
```

Comment: reducing it further to `(bcdedit /enum | Select-String "identifier.*current" -Context 3 ).Context.PostContext[2]`